# I am unable to connect to ec2 instance through Ec2 Instance Connect Option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have Ubuntu 22.04 version AMI instance. I had a notification to reboot instance. Use command: `sudo reboot`. After that command my instance stopped working. After that I am unable to connect the instance with Ec2 Instance Connect option.

The Status check of the Ec2 instance is `1/2 checks passed`

For more information these are my logs:

```
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mEC2 Instance Connect Host Key Harvesting[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRemove Stale Onliâ¦ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mA high performanceâ¦er and a reverse proxy server[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mUser Login Management[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mUnattended Upgrades Shutdown[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mDispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd[0m.
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start [0;1;39mEC2 instance hibernation setup agent[0m.
See 'systemctl status hibinit-agent.service' for details.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mSnap Daemon[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mWait until snapd is fully seeded[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mTime & Date Service[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mTime & Date Service[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mWait until snapd is fully seeded[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mService for snap application lxd.activate[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Stopped [0;1;39mService for snap aâ¦on-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mService for snap aâ¦on-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent[0m.
[[0m[0;31m*     [0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (32s / no limit)
M
[K[[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*    [0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (33s / no limit)
M
[K[[0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*   [0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (33s / no limit)
M
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (34s / no limit)
M
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (34s / no limit)
M
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (35s / no limit)
M
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (35s / no limit)
M
[K[     [0;31m*[0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (36s / no limit)
M
[K[    [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (36s / no limit)
M
[K[   [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*[0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (37s / no limit)
M
[K[  [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m* [0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (37s / no limit)
M
[K[ [0;31m*[0;1;31m*[0m[0;31m*  [0m] A start job is running for Wait forâ¦ to be Configured (38s / no limit)
```

I have made a snapshot of the instance and created new instance and attached the snapshot as root volume for the new instance still can't connect.

Comment: What is generating that log? Is it from the failed instance while it is trying to boot?

Comment: The fact that it is saying `1/2 checks passed` suggests that there is something wrong with the operating system on that boot disk, which is why you cannot connect. See: [Status checks for your instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yup

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with the EC2 instance hibernation setup agent, as indicated by the error message:
First check the status: `systemctl status hibinit-agent.service`
it should looks like:

> hibinit-agent.service - EC2 instance hibernation setup agent
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hibinit-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2023-10-08 13:55:17 UTC; 1 months 16 days ago

May you can turn off the feature and check : use this command `sudo systemctl disable hibinit-agent.service`  then reboot , this should work, and gives you space to connect to your VM , it will not degrade the instance security, instead you can have time to investigate

Comment: how should I connect to instance to execute the commands you mentioned?

Comment: I have tried to access with Ec2 serial console. But my client has forgotten the password